Odoo 17 still using old URL for sale orders and emails? | Change domain used for sale orders in email odoo
we were running our odoo17 hosted on docker using docker compose on domain example1.com and www.example1.com respectively.
We now added another website and another domain to odoo (it's like this: next.newdomain.com)
We setup odoo to handle the multiple websites in the settings.
I changed the web.base.url to https://next.newdomain.com/
and I set web.base.url.Freeze to true
But still, when we send a offer (sale.order) via email, the link to the offer still uses the old domain (and therefore odoo will respond with the old website as well).
what do I need to change for odoo to use the new domain for the email links?
to clarify, this is what I am talking about:

tldr; the button in the image should use our new domain but it still uses the old domain that we used to use to access odoo (we still want to have that domain as a backup but not use it for the email anymore) eventhough we changed web.base.url and web.base.url.Freeze

Should work as intended, but the parameter is written web.base.url.freeze with a lower case f.

@CZoellner, I tried with both lowercase and uppercase, but didn't work. When I change the url from the olddomain website to be none, then odoo will use the new domain for offers. but If i change the domain back, odoo will use the old one again... very strange
